# How come there are multiple dates for Ekadashi fasting?

Tags: fasting, iskcon, ekadashi, swaminarayan

I live in London and I have recently started following Krishna Consciousness. I have also started doing Ekadashi fasting. Recently I made a new friend who also do Ekadashi fasting. We were discussing when is the next Ekadashi, so he mentioned 3rd March but when I checked in my vaishnava calendar, it said 2nd March. I got really confused. I called Iskcon temple and they confirmed it to be on 2nd March. Later I called another temple BAPS Shri Swaminarayan Temple and they said it's on 3rd March.

I am not sure which date to follow and how it's possible that there are two different dates for Ekadashi? Please note both temples are in London so there is no confusion related to different timezone or different locations.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Because tithis change in Drik Panchang(Hindu calendar) according to timezones i.e event might be observed one day ahead in US cities and one day later in Australian cities compare to observance date for Indian cities.Use [this](https://www.prokerala.com/astrology/tithi/) tithi calculator to find when a tithi starts/ends in your timezone.Acc to what i saw Ekadashi tithi starts at 1:09 am on 2nd and is upto 3:19 am on 3rd....Ig the one BAPS is referring to is acc to IST....Hope this helps!